# How do I add a hyperlink in a Slack channel description?

Tags: slack, links

Slack now provides the ability to create formatted hyperlinks in posts but I don't see how to do this in a Channel Description?

How do I add a formatted hyperlink in a Slack Channel Description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slack doesn't give an ability to put formatted text in the channel topic. If you enter the link directly though, it'll be correctly hyperlinked.

This can be confirmed from the API documentation page for [conversations.setTopic](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.setTopic)

> The new topic string. Does not support formatting or linkification.

Comment: Slack needs to catch up to Mattermost on this.

Comment: This answer is out of date IMO

Comment: You actually can link the text in a topic using the API directly.

Comment: @JamesCarr Have you tried it? The API documentation doesn't suggest so.

Comment: @JeffMartin The last I checked, Slack didn't have formatting capabilities for topic string. Could you add more to it?

Comment: Not that it directly addresses the question, but the "Add a Bookmark to Channel" feature might be able to substitute.